# Windows 10 CUDA OpenGL interop memory issue

Tags: c#, c++, windows, opengl, cuda

After switching from Windows 7 to Windows 10 I've noticed that calls to `cuGraphicsGLRegisterImage` to register an OpenGL texture now take double memory.  i.e. after creating a texture that's 200 MB, the register call consumes 400 MB of CUDA memory.  I'm currently running CUDA 8.0.61 (with Patch 2) and OpenGL 4.5 on an M2200 GPU.

This was not the case with Windows 7 on either the K2000 and M2200 GPUs I've ran this code on.

The OpenGL context is using a simple hardware accelerated 32 bit RGBA color, 24 bit depth, 8 bit stencil, double buffered pixel format with no multisampling.

There also appears to be a difference in the amount of available memory returned from 
`glGetInteger(GL_GPU_MEMORY_INFO_CURRENT_AVAILABLE_VIDMEM_NVX)` vs `cuMemGetInfo_v2` that grows in size with each register call.

Does anybody know the cause of the additional memory consumption?  Is it the Windows 10 / CUDA driver?  Is there a way I can fix this or a workaround so that I'm not consuming double memory with my OpenGL / CUDA interops?

Comment: Shot in the dark: Maybe there is internal padding. What happens if you double texture depth from 32 to 64?

Comment: I see no reason why glGetInteger and cuMemGetInfo would return the same value. The former asks for "dedicated video memory, total size (in kb) of the GPU memory", the latter "free and total amount of memory available for allocation by the CUDA context, in bytes".

Comment: I haven't tried double texture depth.  I'll give that a shot.  However, I did notice that if I make the textures sufficiently large, 256 MB on the K2000 and 512 MB on the M2200 that the doubling disappears.  I've tried various powers of 2, and it doesn't seem to correlate with either.

I understand that the two functions wont return the same value (even with factoring in the conversion), but I'd expect the amount of available memory to decrease at the same rate.

Comment: I changed the number of color bits from 32 to 64, and the issue did not go away.