# cudagraphicsglregisterbuffer costs twice size of the OpenGL Buffer

Tags: opengl, cuda

I encountered a strange result, that after calling `cudagraphicsglregisterbuffer` on an OpenGL buffer with size of `sz`, twice memory is cost by checking `cudaMemGetInfo`. The problem can be reproduced by changing the `createVBO` function in the official CUDA example of simpleGL：

```cpp
void createVBO(GLuint *vbo, struct cudaGraphicsResource **vbo_res,
    unsigned int vbo_res_flags)
{
    assert(vbo);

    size_t freeM(0), totalM(0);
    cudaMemGetInfo(&freeM, &totalM);
    size_t freeMPre = freeM;

    // create buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vbo);

    // initialize buffer object
    unsigned int size = mesh_width * mesh_height * 4 * sizeof(float) * 10240;
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    printf(" ================ vbo size: %lu \n", size);
    cudaMemGetInfo(&freeM, &totalM);
    printf(" ================ create vbo cuda mem: %lu \n", (freeMPre - freeM));
    freeMPre = freeM;

    // register this buffer object with CUDA
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(vbo_res, *vbo, vbo_res_flags));

    cudaMemGetInfo(&freeM, &totalM);
    auto regCudaMem = freeMPre - freeM;
    printf(" ================ RegisterBuffer cuda mem: %lu \n", (freeMPre - freeM));
    freeMPre = freeM;

    printf("registered cuda size / vbo size = %f\n", (float)regCudaMem / (float)size);

    SDK_CHECK_ERROR_GL();
}
```

The result of "cuda size / vbo size" is always 2.

In my application, I need to allocate a quite large buffer to interop between CUDA & OpenGL. Therefore, the twice size of memory cost is not affordable.

Is this the inherent behavior of CUDA interop OpenGL? How to avoid it?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450524/windows-10-cuda-opengl-interop-memory-issue) is possibly related